# Create an image of an existing linux installation

Tags: fedora, system-installation, kickstart, cloning

I have installed fedora 19 Xfce and removed a bunch of packages. I need to do a similar installation in multiple other machines. Repeating the process is time consuming.

Is there some way by which I can create an image of the installed OS in its current form?

I followed this guide to create the minimized linux version:
[Check here](https://blackdot.be/2012/06/fedora-17-minimal/)

I started off with a live CD, but this time I would like to have something that would directly install into the system and not follow the live CD procedure, where it first loads the system for live usage and then we can proceed with installation.

Comment: Which way you installing - from liveCD ?

Comment: @MolbOrg please check edit.. :)

Comment: do you know about [kickstart installation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) and is it worth for you to make such

Comment: thats http://serverfault.com/q/549121/214848 looks interesting, but one of the ways just copy by rsync, cp, tar - will also work, maybe with few tweeks after copy